# the return value of a UIInterfaceOrientation object is equal to a boolean var?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiinterfaceorientation

This is a rather basic question regarding the return value from a simple UIInterfaceOrientation object, I try this code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
BOOL orientacion = interfaceOrientation;
return orientacion;
}
```

and the conversion does it, so I thought a UIInterfaceOrientation object is equal to a boolean var?? is that a implicit typo or really UIInterfaceOrientation is equal to a boolean value..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIInterfaceOrientation` is an `enum`, which essentially means it's an integer.  Integers can be assigned to booleans.  Many things can--booleans simply equate to true or false.  If a boolean is set equal to `0` or `nil`, it is false.  If it is set to *anything* other than `0` or `nil` (or some other `#define`d equivalent) it will be true.  Since UIInterfaceOrientation is an enum (an integer), if it is equal to 0 the boolean will be false.  If it is anything but 0 it will be true.

The values of `UIInterfaceOrientation`:

```
typedef enum {
    UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
    UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,            // Device oriented vertically, home button on the bottom
    UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,  // Device oriented vertically, home button on the top
    UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,       // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the right
    UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,      // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the left
    UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,              // Device oriented flat, face up
    UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown             // Device oriented flat, face down
} UIDeviceOrientation;
```

The first on this list will equal `0`.  The next `1`, the next `2`, etc.  So `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown` will set the boolean to false; anything else will set it to true.

---

In any case, you're not using this function correctly.  The code inside this function needs to read:

```
if((interfaceOrientation == someOrientationYouWantToWork) || (interfaceOrientation == someOtherOrientationYouWantToWork)
{
    return YES;
}
else
{
    return NO;
}
```

Set `someOrientationYouWantToWork` etc to values from the enums I posted above.  Whichever orientations you want to work, return `YES` for.  Else it will return `NO`.

Comment: yes I know that example I offer is a bad use, right now I use this: if (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        orientation = true;
    }
    else {
        orientation = false;
    } return orientation;
//the same of this: return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);

Comment: nice answer, small mistake: you are listing t he values of UIDeviceOrientation. UIInterfaceOrientation can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIInterfaceOrientation

Answer (score 1):

It's not a boolean value, but an enumerated value - if it's anything other than 0, it's defaulted to the boolean "YES", otherwise it's "NO".